# Do lambdas have different types?

Tags: c++

Every lambda should have a unique unknown type.. is it guaranteed that two lambdas into the same scope have different types?

```
int main() {
   auto l1 = [](){};
   auto l2 = [](){};   
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(l1), decltype(l2)>::value == false, "Types cannot be equal!");
}
```

This works but I'd like to know if it's guaranteed that the assert will never fire.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, each lambda expression produces a unique type (C++ standard, [expr.prim.lambda]/3):

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a **unique**, unnamed nonunion class type — called the closure type — whose properties are described below.

[emphasis added]

Comment: Any chance you could add a link to the source of the quote for completeness, given that the quote ends "As described below"?

Comment: @IStanley: The `[expr.prim.lambda]/3` is an attribution (it signifies a section in the C++ standard).